# finite unions and intersections

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider the following two propositions about families $\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr{G}$ of subsets of a set $I:$

$(1)$ Whenever a finite intersection of sets of $\mathscr{F}$ is contained in a finite union of subsets of $I,$ one of the sets in the union is a set of $\mathscr{G}$.

$(2)$ Whenever a finite intersection of sets of $\mathscr{F}$ is equal to a finite union of subsets of $I,$ one of the sets in the union is a set of $\mathscr{G}$.

Trivially, $(1)\implies(2)$. But does $(2)\implies(1)?$ Please provide a proof or counter-example. Thank you.

(Note that the word finite above includes empty.)

Answer (score 1):

The implication $2\Longrightarrow 1$ does not hold. To see this take $I=[0,1],$ $\mathscr{F} =\left\{\left[\frac{1}{3} ,\frac{2}{3}\right]\right\},$$\mathscr{G}=\{ (u,v) :0<u,v<1\}.$ Then the families satisfies $2$ but not satisfies $1.$

Comment: These families do not satisfy (2). Taking the empty intersection, we see that $\mathscr{G}$ must contain $[0,1] - X$ or $X$ for every subset $X$ of $[0,1]$. But this is not the case for a subset with two elements {a,b}, in fact not even for a singleton {a}. They also should contain $[1/3,2/3] - X$ or $X$ for every subset of $X$ of $[1/3,2/3]$, which is false for the same reason.

Comment: what do you mean by an empty intersection?

Comment: The intersection of an empty family of sets, *i.e.* the set of all the elements of $I$ which belong to all the sets which are elements of the empty set, *i.e.* $I$ itself.

Comment: The interval $I$ is not equal nor contained in the finite sum of open intervals of the form $(a,b)$ so I do not see where do you see the problem?

Comment: The interval $I$ is equal to the finite union $X\cup(I-X)$, where $X$ is any subset of $I$, therefore, by $(2)$, for any subset $X$ of $I$, $\mathscr{G}$ must contain either $X$ or $(I-X)$ (perhaps both). But your $\mathscr{G}$ contains neither, therefore it fails to satisfy $(2)$.

Comment: Any set $A\subset I$ is contained in a finite union of subsets of $I$ i.e. the finite union is the set $A$ itself. Hence this definition makes no sense.

Comment: Indeed, any set $A$ is contained in (and equal to) the finite union consisting only of $A$ itself. But all this proves is that $\mathscr{F}$ must be contained in $\mathscr{G}$ (or, more generally, any finite intersection of sets in $\mathscr{F}$ must belong to $\mathscr{G}$) in order for conditions $(1)$ or $(2)$ to hold. I do not see why the definitions do not make sense.

Comment: Since if $T=A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ...\cap A_n \subset X_1 \cup X_2 \cup ...\cup X_n $ then $A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ...\cap A_n =( X_1\cap T) \cup (X_2 \cap T) \cup ...\cup (X_n \cap T) $ hence also $2$ implies $1.$

Comment: Assuming $(2)$, we may conclude from there that, if $A_1,…,A_n\in\mathscr{F}$, then, for some $i$, $X_i \cap T \in \mathscr{G}$. The problem is that from $X \cap T \in \mathscr{G}$, and $T$ a finite intersection of sets in $\mathscr{F}$, we may not conclude, in general, that $X\in \mathscr{G}$, as can be seen from the following counter-example: $\mathscr{G}= \mathscr{P}(I)-${$X$}.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a counterexample: take $I$ any set with at least three elements, $\mathscr{F} = \left\{{A}\right\}$, and $\mathscr{G} = \mathscr{P}(I) - \left\{{B}\right\}$, where both $A$ and $B$ are non-empty proper subsets of $I$, and $A$ is a proper subset of $B$.

Here, whenever $A$ or $I$ is equal to a union of subsets of $I$, one of them at least must be different from $B$, since $A \neq B$, $I \neq B$, $A \neq \emptyset$, $I \neq \emptyset$. Thus, $(2)$ is satisfied. But, since $A \subset B$, $(1)$ does not hold.

Thanks [MotylaNogaTomkaMazura](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/235708/motylanogatomkamazura)
for the discussion.